# Enum to string with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, enums

I have a class, and properties like. I am using Entity Framework with Mysql. 
After migration using `add-migration`, it will create an `INT(11)` column. 
But I need `VARCHAR` because, I need Dept or Credit value.

I tried a lot, but it didn't.

How can I do?

```
public class trns
{
     public trans_type enm_trans_type { get; set; } 
}

 public enum trans_type {
    [Description("Dept")]
    Dept,
    [Description("Credit")]
    Credit   
 }
```

Comment: It will be by using CodeFirst, and you will need the reverse version of the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437952/map-string-column-in-entity-framework-to-enum A good article will be http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2014/11/saving-enums-as-strings-with-entity-framework/

Comment: yes, this is correct. http://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2014/11/saving-enums-as-strings-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 1):

Your enumeration is based on an integral value and EF will create an int column behind the scene to store the value of the enum. It is better to store the int value of enumn in database instead of its description and use lookup tables. Then you can simply get description of them using a single join.
 You can use [ef-enum-to-lookup](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup) by [Tim Abell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10245/tim-abell).