# EF Core 3.1 does not allow Contains search on Enum property

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm trying to do a contains search on `enum` property in my `DbSet` and EF Core 3.1 throws the below error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet .Where(d =>
>   d.Position.ToString().Contains("acc"))' could not be translated.
>   Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
>   to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
>   AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()

Entity:

```cs
public class DemoEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Position Position { get; set; }
}
```

Enum - Position:

```cs
public enum Position
{
    [Display(Name = "Accountant")]
    Accountant,
    [Display(Name = "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)")]
    ChiefExecutiveOfficer,
    [Display(Name = "Integration Specialist")]
    IntegrationSpecialist,
    [Display(Name = "Junior Technical Author")]
    JuniorTechnicalAuthor,
    [Display(Name = "Pre Sales Support")]
    PreSalesSupport,
    [Display(Name = "Sales Assistant")]
    SalesAssistant,
    [Display(Name = "Senior Javascript Developer")]
    SeniorJavascriptDeveloper,
    [Display(Name = "Software Engineer")]
    SoftwareEngineer
}
```

DbContext:

```cs
public class DemoDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DemoDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<DemoEntity> Demos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .Entity<DemoEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.Position)
            .HasConversion<string>();
    }
}
```

When I query the table as follows I'm getting the error

```cs
try
{
    var test = await _context.Demos.Where(x => x.Position.ToString().Contains("acc")).ToListAsync();
}
catch (System.Exception e)
{
    //throw;
}
```

The Position is of type `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in my database.

[image]

[image]

This is not possible? If so please can you help me with explanation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has been logged in [efcore github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20604) and here is the workaround for this now. The `enum` property needs to be casted into `object` and then to `string`

```cs
var test = await _context.Demos.Where(x => ((string) (object)x.Position).Contains("acc")).ToListAsync();
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: Will this approach works if the int value of enum is saved to db ? How can we apply where condition in case of int value

Comment: It has to work. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: system.invalidcastexception unable to cast object of type enum to type 'system.string'

Comment: Works great but note there is a small typo. Should be: `((string) (object)x.Position)`

Comment: Note that `x.Position` is translated to `CAST([x].[Position] AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`, thus unless Position is already `NVARCHAR(MAX)` the `CAST()` will slow down the query significantly. A better version I found is to define both the enum and string like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24939927/995369